# Git repository sharing through tomcat7 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have installed the tomcat7 git-core jenkins.

I am trying to do the local build jobs in the git repository. Can anyone help me in sharing the git repository with all operations - git clone, pull, push, tags, revisions, etc.,

I dont know where I am failing to share the git.

Even I share the directory, I am able to clone, pull the changes from the branch but not able to push the changes.

Can you list the procedure to share the git repo with tomcat7?

Comment: Have you ever read anything about jenkins and job configuration?

Comment: I am happy with Jenkins job configuration since it has nice UI to configure.

But I am unable to see git documentation for sharing the bare repository.

And there are so many approaches - http, gitolite, webdav, cgi, smart http, etc.,

Comment: Take the one you prefer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably go through this below tutorial and you can achieve what you want:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm

Few Direction:
Make sure all your tools are in place and you have super user access:
Use the below command:

```
$ sudo adduser git
$ su git
$ cd
$ mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Next, you need to add some developer SSH public keys to the authorized_keys file for the git user. Let’s assume you have some trusted public keys and have saved them to temporary files. Again, the public keys look something like this:

```
$ cat /tmp/id_rsa.john.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCB007n/ww+ouN4gSLKssMxXnBOvf9LGt4L
ojG6rs6hPB09j9R/T17/x4lhJA0F3FR1rP6kYBRsWj2aThGw6HXLm9/5zytK6Ztg3RPKK+4k
Yjh6541NYsnEAZuXz0jTTyAUfrtU3Z5E003C4oxOj6H0rfIF1kKI9MAQLMdpGW1GYEIgS9Ez
Sdfd8AcCIicTDWbqLAcU4UpkaX8KyGlLwsNuuGztobF8m72ALC/nLF6JLtPofwFBlgc+myiv
O7TCUSBdLQlgMVOFq1I2uPWQOkOWQAHukEOmfjy2jctxSDBQ220ymjaNsHT4kgtZg2AYYgPq
dAv8JggJICUvax2T9va5 gsg-keypair
```

You just append them to the git user’s authorized_keys file in its .ssh directory:

```
$ cat /tmp/id_rsa.john.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ cat /tmp/id_rsa.josie.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ cat /tmp/id_rsa.jessica.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, you can set up an empty repository for them by running git init with the --bare option, which initializes the repository without a working directory:

```
$ cd /opt/git
$ mkdir project.git
$ cd project.git
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /opt/git/project.git/
```

Then people can push the first version of their project into that repository by adding it as a remote and pushing up a branch. Note that someone must shell onto the machine and create a bare repository every time you want to add a project. Let’s use gitserver as the hostname of the server on which you’ve set up your git user and repository. If you’re running it internally, and you set up DNS for gitserver to point to that server, then you can use the commands pretty much as is (assuming that myproject is an existing project with files in it):

```
$ cd myproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
$ git push origin master
```

At this point, the others can clone it down and push changes back up just as easily:

```
$ git clone git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
$ cd project
$ vim README
$ git commit -am 'fix for the README file'
$ git push origin master
```

With this method, you can quickly get a read/write Git server up and running for a handful of developers.

You can edit the shell for a user using chsh :

```
$ sudo chsh git  # and enter the path to git-shell, usually: /usr/bin/git-shell
```

The git user can only use the SSH connection to push and pull Git repositories and can’t shell onto the machine. If you try, you’ll see a login rejection like this:

```
$ ssh git@gitserver
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
Connection to gitserver closed.
```

Source: git-scm